# Remove footer text in the wordpress blog

Tags: function, wordpress

I created the testing blog in that I found the footer message like

```
Proudly powered by WordPress .
```

How to remove those footer message without editing the core file there is the options to remove the footer in the blog.

Or else if any other custom functions to remove the footer message.

Thanks.

Comment: YOU CAN TRY CSS TO hide the message

Answer (score 0):

You can edit it from template

goto `Appearance` -> `Editor` and select `Footer` from the right side and remove

`<?php printf( __( 'Proudly powered by %s', 'twentytwelve' ), 'WordPress' ); ?>` line or edit it

Comment: See '<?php
function copyright() {
echo "this is the footer message";
}
add_action('wp_footer','copyright');
?>' I need to add the footer in the wp_footer hook ,I need if any other hook to remove the footer message.